# Get color code and background image file of any website

Tags: css

To learn CSS and jQuery, I want to prepare exact layout of any website. While viewing any website, I want a tool which can return the hexa-decimal color of the background used in a Div.

If the background is an image, when I click View-Source in the browser, is it possible to download that image file? Is it possible to view the CSS?

I don't want to use Dreamweaver, I only want to make use of any open-source free tool.

Comment: Use addons in your browser like color picker, firebug, web developer and pixlr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add firebug addon in your firefox and try inspecting the DOM of page you wish by just hittin F12 on your keyboard.

Comment: IE has inbuilt IE developer toolbar which can be opened by hitting F12 but as per my knowledge there is no stable version of code debugger for IE other than its inbuilt developer tools.

Comment: Is FireBug able to show the CSS used?

Comment: ya.. you can use firebug to see the CSS